# Cloud flare Super Cache Plugin Issue

Tags: wordpress, caching, cloudflare

I need help on deleting the cache our live site [www.burmart.com](http://www.burmart.com). Website is not down, but the cache saved the screen shot while the server down and error page is show in homepage. I currently used Cloud flare and Super Cache plugin. I already purge cache from plugin and also from cloud flare account but still not delete the cache. Is there any other place to delete the cache.

Current issue page: https://www.burmart.com
You can access with: https://www.burmart.com/?swfpc=1

Answer (score 0):

That's not a cache issue, CF does not cache the error pages. Usually it's Error 1101 thrown by CloudFlare Worker. This usually happens, when the script throws a Javascript exception.

But from my understanding of the problem I believe you just have bad configuration of the CloudFlare routing/workers/api .. please check all sections or simply remove your site and re-add it the DNS and leave everything on default, if it's working then you can play with the settings and see what did you do to break it again. :)